# Programmatically fill IRS forms

Tags: c#, itext

I'm trying to fill IRS forms (for example https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ZpqwUusHIOKToKhf8eufywS_8lGxcDuGo0AcNGsQmyw/edit#)
programmatically using ITextSharp:

```
var file = @"w8BENEV1021.pdf";
        var fileS = @"w8BENEV1021_1.pdf";
        using (var reader = new PdfReader(file))
        {
            reader.RemoveUsageRights(); // This is needed for some readers (acrobat) so they will not show pop that we sealed the file to changes

            using (var memStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (var stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, memStream))
                {
                    AcroFields fields = stamper.AcroFields;

                    fields.SetField("topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].f1_1[0]", "nameodfodod");
                    fields.SetField("topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].c1_1[12]", "13");
                    fields.SetField("topmostSubform[0].Page2[0].c2_5[0]", "11");

                    stamper.FormFlattening = true;
                    stamper.Close();

                    var data = memStream.ToArray();
                    File.WriteAllBytes(fileS, data);
                }
            }
        }
```

I was wondering how do I know to which control in the PDF does each key maps to (like topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].f1_1[0])
is there some GUI that shows that?

Comment: Unprotect your example document...

Comment: From the names of your fields it looks like you are dealing with XFA Forms. So you will need to use Adobe LiveCycle designed as GUI to find the match between visual controls and the field names